# If $X_t$ is an ARIMA(1,1,1) process, what is $Y_t = Y_{t-1} + X_t$?

Tags: time-series

Q: If $X_t$ is an ARIMA(1,1,1) process, what is $Y_t = Y_{t-1} + X_t$?

Attempted solution:
$X_t$ is an ARIMA(1,1,1), i.e $\nabla X_t = X_t - X_{t-1} = Z_t $ where $Z_t$ is a casual ARMA(1,1) process and satisfies  $(1-\phi_1 B)Z_t = (1+\theta_1B)\epsilon_t. $ Since $Z_t$ is casual, we may write $Z_t = \frac{1 + \theta_1 B}{1-\phi_1 B} \epsilon_t $.

Then $X_t = \frac{1}{1-B}  \frac{1 + \theta_1 B}{1-\phi_1 B} \epsilon_t$, and

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(1-B)Y_t &= X_t \\
(1-B)Y_t &= \frac{1}{1-B}  \frac{1 + \theta_1 B}{1-\phi_1 B} \epsilon_t \\
(1-B)^2(1-\phi_1 B)Y_t &= (1+\theta_1B)\epsilon_t
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So $Y_t$ is an ARMA(3,1) process?

Comment: From what you've written, isn't $Y_t$ an $\text{ARIMA}(1,2,1)$ process? I mean, $Y_t$ has to be differenced once to get $X_t$, which has to be differenced once to get $Z_t$ which is a causal $\text{ARMA}(1,1)$ process. So $Y_t$ is differenced twice to get an ARMA process, i.e. the index of integration equals $2$.

Comment: Makes sense. How do you formulate it mathematically?

Comment: To me at least, the "mathematical" formulation is that an ARIMA process is given by the last differencing equation which you wrote. Namely, if you see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average#Definition) at the last line of the section "Definition", there is an exact formula for the difference equation satisfied by an ARIMA$(p,d,q)$, which is exactly what you wrote with $p=1,d=2,q=1$.